# Link GitLab Build Status to Jenkins Build Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gitlab

I've configured Jenkins to report build statuses back to GitLab using the following Jenkins plug-in: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitLab+Plugin. The build statues is shown in GitLab as expected; however, if I click on the build status it takes me to a GitLab 404 page instead of the Jenkins job. I think this is because GitLab tries to take you to a GitLab CI status page. Is there a way to get these link to point to the Jenkins job instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I hadn't enabled the pipelines feature in the GitLab settings for the repository.